# Possible to log X-FORWARDED-FOR to nginx error_log?

Tags: nginx, log-files, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

Nginx allows custom log formats for access logs -- right now I'm logging http_x_forwarded_for and it's working fine.

The problem is my error log only shows the LB IP.  After Googling and reading through their documentation, it seems error_log doesn't support a custom format, only setting the log level (info, alert, notice, warning, etc).

Is there any kind of workaround or module I could use to get around this?

For completeness, my setup is:

Amazon ELB -> pool of instances running nginx as a reverse proxy to php-fpm 7.0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be using the [real IP module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html), so that the client's actual IP address is considered the remote IP address, rather than your load balancer's IP address. This way, you won't have to check X-Forwarded-For in your logs, nor in your application either.

It is simple to enable it, just supply your load balancer IP address(es):

```
set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
set_real_ip_from  172.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

Comment: This worked, I thought I had tried this module before (or something similarly named) and it didn't work/had some other reason we couldn't use it (this was at least 1-2 years ago).

This seems to have done the trick for now -- though it's not perfect as we're still using EC2 Classic for this cluster/NonVPC ELB IPs change all the time, so we have to use the whole 10.0.0.0/8 range in your example.  Thanks.